# Client-side QA Testing Approaches?

Tags: cme, content-manager

I get this question every few clients:

**How might a QA team automate parts of testing a Content Manager (Explorer) setup?**

- I've seen [Watir with Ruby](http://idonotalwaystestmycode.blogspot.com/2012/07/testing-tridion-implementation-with.html) mentioned with at least SDL Tridion 2009 (it's quite of an involved setup, though).
- For Web applications in general, I've used Selenium for user testing. Has anyone done much with it and SDL Tridion (within the CME)?
- Not quite the same as *user actions in a browser*, but we have SDL Tridion's supported extension points to collect statistics and monitor use actions:

  - Event System, as seen in the [Reporting Framework](https://code.google.com/p/tridion-2011-reporting/)
  - Core Service, as seen in this [PowerShell script that gathers CM statistics](http://amarchuk.blogspot.com/2012/11/powershell-script-to-gather-some.html)
  - GUI Extensions (e.g. Google Analytics against the CME)

**What have you seen organizations use and/or what would you recommend for QA teams for testing the CME and maybe Experience Manager?**

Comment: Great question Alvin Reyes. We have not able to automate so far, tried iMacros FF plug-in (but had issues with creating components and assembling pages etc.. different publications). Currently we do all manually and our clients are not happy at all. Often we get questioned what does the product offers from testing side (whitepapers, best practices, samples etc..), bcuz every release of the product requires testing cycle from product end. I am really interested in seeing some thing officially from SDL Tridion which works and should extend from there.. Keep posted if you come across any nice.

Comment: If there's an approach that might work for your scenarios, definitely make a recommendation on [SDL Tridion Ideas](http://ideas.sdltridion.com/). I'm likely biased by being wary of a "must work with testing framework X" requirement on top of the features, backwards compatibility, and existing scenarios the CMS must support. In the end the CME is for real users and automation can get us so far. I do have a "stuff to test" post in the works, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regardless of the testing tool, in order to simulate real users using CME and Experience Manager we will need to focus on http requests to the internal CME/Experience WCF services.

You will need to make sure to pass all the header needed like the X-SDLTridion-Token. Additionally depending on the operation you are performing you will need to pass the appropriated POST message in JSON format and manage the response in JSON format as well.

I have done automation test script using JMeter (a free tool) but I think the same approach will be followed by other commercial tools.

For instance if you want to include test for saving components.

- Use this URL: `/WebUI/Models/TCM54/Services/General.svc/SaveItem`
- Make sure you have this header: `X-SDL-Tridion-Token`
- Pass this JSON format in the POST: `{"id":"tcm:3-1055","xml":"[COMPONENT XML]","doneEditing":true}`

Comment: Eric, what about Tridion 2013? These internal services, how you call them remain untouched usually or they change? So does making a complex testing tool makes sense or not...? Thanks!

Comment: For Tridion 2013 they haven't changed. But R&D can remove or modify them without notice since they are internal and not documented. To be honest I wouldn't develop a complex testing tool by myself, I would use a testing tool like Mercury or a free one like JMeter (very nice tool).